# I don't understand why these numbers came out the way they did in c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, double

I ran these codes but I got a really weird number. I'm new to c++

ii) Predict the outputs for the following snippets of code:

a)

```
int x=75, y=105;
printf(" %c %lf " , x,y);
```

for the first one i got x is equal to K. This I understand
but for y I got 0, is it because it was declared as int and not double?

b)

```
float pH=5.65582; 
printf (" %d %lf" , pH,pH);
```

Now this one is so weird. For the first pH it's 1073741824. I don't even know how they got it. And for the second pH is 2. How?
c)

```
float p=0.345689;
double q=0.445566778899;
printf ( "%d %f %lf" , p*q, p*q, p/q);
printf ("%d %0.5f %9.3f", p+q , p-q, p*(p+q));
```

p*q -1713662420

p*q -0.000000

p/q -0.000000

p+q -1561213759

p-q 0

p*(p+q) a really long number

591890496450433740000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) might be somewhat relevant....

Comment: I think ``1073741824`` should be actually the direct interpretation of internal representation of floating number ``5.65582``.

Comment: As maligned as `iostream`s are by some, this is a prime example of why `std::cout` should be used over `printf`, at least until simple learning mistakes are in the past.

Comment: If you're new to C++ you shouldn't be doing this kind of problem. The results depend on knowing the details of how floating-point values are represented on your hardware and how your compiler passes arguments to variadic functions, neither of which is specified by the language definition. You've gotten some guesses that seem to be based on particular assumptions about those details, but even if they're right, if you change compilers or computers you may well get different results. Formally, this is deep in the realm of what the standard calls "undefined behavior".

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong `printf` format specifiers for the types of the arguments you're passing.

To print a `float` or `double` value, use `"%f"`, `"%g"`, or `"%e"`, or some variant. For an `int` argument, use `"%d"`.

By using a particular format string, you're promising to pass an argument of the proper type. If you fail to do so, you're lying to `printf`, and the resulting behavior is undefined. Don't do that.

(What's probably happening is that, for example, `printf` is taking the representation of the `int` argument you actually give it, and *assuming* that it's the representation of a `double` object. But don't waste time figuring out why you got the results you did. Just fix the code.)

Comment: 1073741824 is the low 32 bits of `5.65582`, and -1713662420 is the low 32 bits of `p*q`. I do not see a match for -1561213759.

Comment: Do you have to? The fact that it's undefined behaviour should be an indication that patterns you find will not always hold true.

Comment: @chris: No, you do not have to find a match. But sometimes people learn things by looking behind the curtain.

Comment: The first `printf` prints “2” for `%lf` because the high 32 bits of `5.65582` were consumed by `%lf`, leaving the low 32 bits followed by the high 32 bits of the next copy. As stated previously, the low 32 bits are 1073741824 (0x40000000), which starts a floating-point number near 2. Then the next 32 bits are too low in value to change the display at the default precision, so “2” is printed.

Comment: Ah, -1561213759 is the low 32 bits of `p+q`.

Answer (score 1):

The actual representation of a `double` and `float` and `int` is very different inside the machine. Incorrect format specifiers in `printf` will try to interpret this binary representation as of the particular type.

Garbage in - garbage out

Comment: The difference between `float` and `double` representations is not relevant here; `float` arguments are promoted to `double`. The problem is that the OP is mixing integers and floating-point.

Comment: @KeithThompson yes I was also going to add `int` in the mix. I forgot =P

Comment: But I was given that exact code and write down what I expect as output. Would my answers be acceptable or I'm missing something here?.

Comment: @KavinThipthamai: Who gave you this code, and why would you expect any particular output given format strings that do not match the parameter types?

Comment: My TA for my class. It was for hw assignment.

Comment: Reeking of undefined behaviour like this? If the assignment itself wasn't an exercise in seeing the effects of undefined behaviour, make sure you get that changed for next time.

Comment: @KavinThipthamai: This was a bad homework assignment, unless you were supposed to answer that the code provided has behavior that is not defined by the C++ standard.